# Filtering data with more than n repetitions by taking a mean of those repetitions

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, dplyr

I have time-series data at one-minute interval (data frame name is pn.nano). I wish to convert it into 5-minute averaged data. But before averaging, it should be ensured that each 5-minute interval has at least 3 values (i.e. each 5-min interval should have at least 3 minutes of data). Then only averaging should be done otherwise the data should be filtered out.

The data looks as follows. The column names (11.5, 15.4, etc.) are the pollutants whose variation with time is being monitored.

```
nano.pn <- structure(list(datetime = structure(c(1491887640, 1491887700, 
           1491887760, 1491887820, 1491887880, 1491887940, 1491888000, 1491888060, 
           1491888120, 1491888180), tzone = "Asia/Calcutta", class = c("POSIXct", 
           "POSIXt")), `11.5` = c(5938.99, 5530.35, 4825.41, 4439.71, 4357.98, 
           4467.01, 3956.29, 3880.23, 3469.57, 3356.23), `15.4` = c(9594.94, 
           9124.55, 8382.42, 8223.1, 8216.26, 8454.1, 8112.84, 7519.49, 
           7060.94, 7337.3), `20.5` = c(5126.89, 4965.06, 4749.27, 4941.16, 
           5081.44, 5254.23, 5424.79, 4855.33, 4790.21, 5149.6), `27.4` = c(2936.92, 
           2882.55, 2704.88, 2856.22, 2868.12, 2909.07, 3106.77, 2887.35, 
           2802.64, 2853.24), `36.5` = c(1768.23, 1770.75, 1584.26, 1619.82, 
           1558.73, 1610.95, 1587.24, 1557.97, 1481.79, 1323.94)), row.names = c(NA, 
           -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

My approach is to use the following code:

```
x <- nano.pn %>% mutate(datetime= floor_date(datetime, unit = "5 mins"))
n <- x %>% group_by(datetime) %>% summarise(countt= n())
n.pn.5min <- x %>% mutate(countt= rep(n$countt,n$countt)) %>% filter(countt>2) %>% 
                   group_by(datetime) %>% summarise_all(mean, na.rm= TRUE)
```

Although this works fine, is there any better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work:

```
> nano.pn %>% mutate(cuttime = cut(datetime, '5 mins')) %>% group_by(cuttime) %>% filter(n() > 3) %>% summarise(across(is.numeric, mean, na.rm = 1))
`summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
# A tibble: 2 x 6
  cuttime             `11.5` `15.4` `20.5` `27.4` `36.5`
  <fct>                <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 2017-04-11 10:44:00  5018.  8708.  4973.  2850.  1660.
2 2017-04-11 10:49:00  3826.  7697.  5095.  2912.  1512.
>
```

The difference between my result and Thomas's is that when he used flood_date, the first row in the data frame that had time "10:44:00.000" changed to "10:40:00.000" and wasn't included in the mean calculation as it was the only observation in that group and second group had 4 rows. Mine has 5 in both groups. So please use which ever code would work for you.

Comment: Thanks, Karthik for pointing that out. Your code made me realize that I should use ceiling_date rather than floor_date. But yes I may need your type of code too sometime in near future. 
I had one more doubt if you could help out. If I have another dataset at 5-min interval and I wish to take the mean of this data as per the timeline of the second dataset, is it possible?

Comment: Sure, you mean same pollutant values but in different timelines?

Comment: Let me try with an example.

Let's say I have an independent variable dataset "A" at a 1-min interval and I have a dependent variable dataset "B" at a 5-min interval. I want to take a 5-min average of data "A" but on the same timeline as data "B". Is it possible? If I use a function like left_join(), it will only give the matching values of both datasets but wont take the average.

Comment: Because they are dependent, you could join as long as the datetime matches. i.e. as above, if the data in "A" is grouped into same intervals as "B" you can join.

Comment: I think it will be better to post it with an example. I will do that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like below?

```
nano.pn %>%
  mutate(datetime = floor_date(datetime, unit = "5 mins")) %>%
  group_by(datetime) %>%
  filter(n() >= 3) %>%
  summarise_all(mean, na.rm = TRUE)
```

which gives

```
# A tibble: 2 x 6
  datetime            `11.5` `15.4` `20.5` `27.4` `36.5`
  <dttm>               <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 2017-04-11 10:45:00  4724.  8480.  4998.  2844.  1629.
2 2017-04-11 10:50:00  3666.  7508.  5055.  2912.  1488.
```

Comment: I didn't know that n() could be used within the filter() itself. Thanks.